# Interval in Java with user choosing min and max value

Tags: java, input, intervals

I've been sitting with this problem for literally 3 hours and I'm starting to get real frustrated. I've got a few assignments from school that I'm supposed to solve and present for the teacher/students. I've solved everything except for this ONE problem that I just can't wrap my head around in any way.

So, the instructions for this problem are as follows:

> The method should ask for an interval where the user gets to choose a minimum and maximum number. The method will write a series of numbers that start with the minimum value and then every 7th number. It should never write a number that is greater than the maximum value.
>   To clarify (example):

```
Min = 26
Max = 57
```

The program writes: `26, 33, 40, 47, 54`

This is my code:

```
String minimum, maximum;
    int mini, maxi;

        minimum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert smallest number");
        mini = Integer.parseInt(minimum);
        maximum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert biggest number");
        maxi = Integer.parseInt(maximum);
        for(int i = mini ; i <= maxi ; i++ ) {
        if(i<maxi) {
            System.out.print( mini + ", ");
        } else {
            System.out.print( mini );
        }
        mini +=7;
```

I realize what `i <= maxi ;` does, but I don't know what to replace it with. I've tried to come up with a formula to make it work, but failed every time... I've only been studying Java for like a week so please take it easy. I hope there is a kind soul out there SOMEWHERE who can clarify this for me. I will return the favor to the community down the line when I have more knowledge. Cheers.

Comment: i += 7 should replace i++ and you could then print i instead of mini

Comment: OMG why didn't I think of that... You are such a nice person man, thank you A LOT for not only helping me out, but also making me understand why it works now. My brain can now rest as I feel the peace return once again :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is change `mini` to `i` for everything except the assignment of `i` and then change `i++` to `i +=7`

```
for(int i = mini ; i <= maxi; i+=7) {
    if(i<maxi) {
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
    } else {
        System.out.print(i);
    }       
}
```

***Output:***

```
26, 33, 40, 47, 54
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! You and Dylan helped me out. I KNEW there was an easy solution, my brain was just overheating from a few hours of wrongful thinking. This community is the best. I hope you have a great night (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
 for(; mini <= maxi ; mini+=7 ) {
        if(mini <maxi) {
            System.out.print( mini + ", ");
        } else {
            System.out.print( mini );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is really no need to check if i is less than maxi again,
 I guess it's for the comma sake but it can be simplify as below.

```
 for(int i = mini ; i <= maxi; i+=7) {System.out.println(i); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the mini value, let it be as it is and use i instead of mini for the for loop, this much should do, further do you want the last comma to be printed ?

```
for(int i = mini ; i <= maxi;i=i+7) {
    if(i<maxi) {
        System.out.print( i + ", ");
    }   
}
```